# When i change from crudrepository to pagingand sortingrepository there is no save method

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, crud-repository

When i change from crudrepository to pagingandsortingrepository there is no save method and the application begins to fail

```
      error: cannot find symbol
                courses.save(course);
                       ^
      symbol:   method save(Course)
      location: variable courses of type CourseRepository
```

I have tried extending both

Answer (score 6):

[PagingAndSortingRepository](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html) repository has mainly been created for fetching records and not modify it.

In this case your repository interface can extend both [PagingAndSortingRepository](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html) & [CrudRepository](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html)

Comment: All your links go to the javadoc for `CrudRepository`

Comment: You can extend both of them : public interface YourRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<T, ID>, CrudRepository<T, ID>

Answer (score 4):

According to [Interface PagingAndSortingRepository](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/PagingAndSortingRepository.html), there is no save method in this interface. Hence your code is failing.

But [Interface CrudRepository](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html) has a save method.

Also, this hierarchy might help to clear the picture even more:

[image]

Comment: ok so i just need to extend both?

Comment: Why not use JpaRepository and have best of both worlds!

Comment: Yes you could as the java doc of the PagingAndSortigRepository Interface suggests. https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/PagingAndSortingRepository.html#:~:text=Repository%20fragment%20to,Author%3A

Comment: @hiren good question, i am following a pluralsight course, i often wonder why